# How to play on local in MPV camera AV output from remote via SSH?

Tags: ssh, ffmpeg, camera, mpv-media-player

I need simple thing, play on local in MPV camera AV output from remote via SSH.

I thought it should be simple like this.

```
ssh 192.168.1.100 -p 22 'ffmpeg -i /dev/video0 -b:v 1M -b:a 150K -' | mpv -
```

But it fails.

```
Input #0, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 2740.580412, bitrate: 147456 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (YUY2 / 0x32595559), yuyv422, 640x480, 147456 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
[NULL @ 0x555639eb3480] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'pipe:'
pipe:: Invalid argument
Failed to recognize file format.


Exiting... (Errors when loading file)
```

What is wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell ffmpeg which output container format / muxer (`-f`) to use when using a pipe:

```
ssh -p 22 192.168.1.100 'ffmpeg -i /dev/video0 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -b:v 1M -b:a 150k -f mpegts -' | mpv -
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. It shows me some fails, but it is working. Maybe just for info, what does it mean? `[ffmpeg] AVHWDeviceContext: Failed to query surface attributes: 20 (the requested function is not implemented).
[vo/gpu/vaapi-egl] failed to retrieve libavutil frame constraints
`

Comment: @genderbee Never seen that before. Must be from `mpv` which I am not as familiar with.

Comment: And sound is not working, but it is related to audio interface on remote? Thanks.

Comment: @genderbee Your input (from what I can tell from your partial ffmpeg console output) does not contain any sound.

Comment: This is not audio identification? `-c:a aac` `-b:a 150k` What I need to add?

Comment: @genderbee You have to add an input that has audio. ffmpeg shows that your camera does not provide any audio. `-c:a aac` sets the audio encoder and `-b:a 150k` sets the audio bitrate, but they are ignored if you do not have any audio inputs.